# If Soulflayer exiles a Winged Sliver from the graveyard via delve does it gain flying?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Soulflayer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soulflayer) has delve and reads

> If a creature card with flying was exiled with Soulflayer's delve
> ability, Soulflayer has flying. The same is true for first strike,
> double strike, deathtouch, haste, hexproof, indestructible, lifelink,
> reach, trample, and vigilance.

[Winged Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Winged%20Sliver) reads

> All Sliver creatures have flying.

My question is... does Soulflayer gain flying if a Winged Sliver that was in the graveyard is exiled?

Comment: I have updated my answer with another tidbit I found when looking closer at the Winged Silver page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Winged Sliver does not have flying but grants itself that ability along with all other sliver creatures. The first ruling on the [Soulflayer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soulflayer) page says that it does not happen.

> Creature cards that have abilities that grant the listed keyword abilities to themselves won’t count. For example, exiling a Battle Brawler (a creature with “As long as you control a red or white permanent, Battle Brawler gets +1/+0 and has first strike”) with Soulflayer’s delve ability won’t cause Soulflayer to have first strike, even if you control a red or white permanent.

Also, for further clarification on the [Winged Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Winged%20Sliver) page

> If the creature type of a Sliver changes so it’s no longer a Sliver, it will no longer be affected by its own ability. Its ability will continue to affect other Sliver creatures.